# Fragment with BroadCastReceiver for phoneStateChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a `BroadCastReceiver` in one of my fragments to catch phone events.

For some reason my `onReceive`is never called, I never get to se ¡e the Log on any missed call, rejected call, calling, dialing....etc

This is what I have done so far:

In my `onCreateView` I have

```
 test = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("broad","RECEIVED EVENT");
        }
    };
```

In addition, in my Manifest I have added the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And I have registered/unregistered the receiver in my `onResume` and `onDestroy` with the desired filter:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(test,filter);
    }


@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(test);
    }
```

Comment: have you checked if your fragment's `onResume()` is getting called or not, if not  check it first

Comment: yes checked both of them with `Log`statement, and can confirm they are called, I might be doing something wrong that I have nor found....yet